# bind multiple events on multiple DOM node in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Says I have a chess layout, which has lots of node like

```
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
..till 100
```

How can I add event to them? If I do the normal way, like

```
<div onClick={this.doSomething.bind(this)}>1</div>
```

means I have to have 100 event binding on 100 DOM node. I don't see that make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first, If you have a list of node, you can render by `ListNodes.map((node,index)=>{renderOneNode()})`.

The Second, In the `function renderOneNode()`, you can add one event for all of nodes.
example:

```js
ListNodes.map((node,index)=>{
  return (
   <div onClick={this.doSomething.bind(this,node)}>{index}<div>
);
})
```

The function `doSomething(node)` to control the node which you are clicking.